# Can't enable tail call optimization in node v6.4.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, ecmascript-6

I wan't to play around with tail call optimization in node/es2015, but I keep getting `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. So I tried a very simple test function:

```
  function countTo(n, acc) {
    if(n === 0) {
      return acc;
    }
    return countTo(n - 1, acc + n);
  }

  console.log(countTo(100000 , 0))
```

and it still fails.  I've tried adding `'use strict';` inside the function body and at the top of the file.  I've tried using `--harmony` and `--harmony-tailcalls`

The same function works as expected in racket:

```lisp
#lang racket
(define count-to
  (lambda (n acc)
    (cond
      ((= n 0) acc)
      (else (count-to (- n 1) (+ acc n))))))
(count-to 100000000 0)
; ~> 5000000050000000
```

## Edit:

#### As @MatthieuLemoine suggested.  It works in v6.5.0+ with `"use strict";` and either `--harmony` or `--harmony-tailcalls`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using node v6.5.0, the following works :

```
function countTo(n, acc) {
  'use strict';
  if(n === 0) {
    return acc;
  }
  return countTo(n - 1, acc + n);
}
console.log(countTo(100000 , 0));
```

Running with `--harmony-tailcalls` flag :

```
node --harmony-tailcalls tco.js
```

Comment: That worked.  I upgraded to v6.6.0 and it worked. I thought v6.4.0 would have been enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [tco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tco) module to emulate a tail call optimization even on old node. I'll add an example using your code to this answer in a minute.

Slightly changing your code, you can run even 10 million levels of recursion:

```
var tco = require('tco');
var countTo = tco(function (n, acc) {
  if (n === 0) {
    return [null, acc];
  }
  return [countTo, [n - 1, acc + n]];
});
console.log(countTo(10000000, 0));
```

You can use Sweet macros to make it look more like:

```
var countTo = tco(function (n, acc) {
  if (n === 0) {
    ret acc;
  }
  ret countTo(n - 1, acc + n);
});
console.log(countTo(10000000, 0));
```

Which is basically changing `return` to `ret` but currently my macros that I used before don't seem to work with the current version of Sweet.js - I have to investigate it when I have some time.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of that module.

Comment: Cool module! I've been interested in sweet.js for a while but have never used it.  My code should work though.  I'm using v6.4.0

Comment: @sheepdog Thanks. I wrote it out of frustration a year ago or something. Thanks for posting your question because actually I didn't know that tail call optimization should be available in the current version of Node - I wonder why it didn't hit the news because it's a big feature that I was waiting for. The lack of tail call optimiation was always the biggest single shortcoming of JavaScript in my opinion.